# Install RPM package in Ubuntu as .deb

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Using alien, I can convert RPM format package into .deb package.

The question is, which is the best way to handle RPM format package in Ubuntu/Debian? Should I use alien to convert it to .deb and install using dpkg, or install RPM and use it to install the the RPM format package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alien is the system to use. As the [Debian `rpm` package](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/rpm) description states:

> `If you want to install Red Hat Packages then please use the alien package. Using rpm directly will bypass the Debian packaging system!`

Typically, you do not want that. If at all possible, I recommend rebuilding the software from source for a Debian system. Alien will simply move files around, add scripts and change the archive to be dpkg compatible. It will not fix executables linked to non-existant or wrongly-versioned libraries.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is to keep all packages in a single system; by using Alien to convert the package you can still work with it via apt/aptitute/synaptic.